# template vs. constructor parameters for numerically-parametrized sets

Tags: c++, templates

I am relatively new to c++ templates, and am implementing some numerical routines.  In particular, I have been looking through some code whose style is such that if it were to define a vector, it would be as

```
template <class Field>
class Vector2
{
    private:
    std::vector<Field> container;

    public:
    Vector2(size_t size) : container(std::vector<Field>(size, Field(0))) {}
    Vector2(const Vector2<Field> &source) : container(source.container) {}

          Field & operator[](size_t index) { return container.at(index); }
    const Field & operator[](size_t index) const { return container.at(index); }

    Vector2<Field> operator+( const Vector2<Field> & rhs) const {
        if (rhs.container.size() != container.size())
            throw new std::invalid_argument("wrong size");

        Vector2<Field> sum(*this);
        for (int i = 0; i < container.size(); i++)
            sum[i] += rhs[i];
        return sum;
    }
};
```

However, if I were designing the class template, I would have chosen to specify the size in the template parameter:

```
template <int size, class Field>
class Vector1
{
    private:
    std::vector<Field> container;

    public:
    Vector1() : container(std::vector<Field>(size, Field(0))) {}
    Vector1(const Vector1<size, Field> &source) : container(source.container) {}

    Field & operator[](size_t index) { return container.at(index); }
    const Field & operator[](size_t index) const { return container.at(index); }

    Vector1<size, Field> operator+( const Vector1<size, Field> & rhs) const {
        Vector1<size, Field> sum;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            sum[i] += rhs[i];
        return sum;
    }
};
```

My thinking is that this would prevent things like adding two vectors of different dimensions, since they would be different classes.  In particular, something like

```
Vector1<double> a (3);
Vector1<double> b (4);
Vector1<double> c = a + b;
```

would need run-time checking of the sizes, yet

```
Vector2<3,double> a;
Vector2<4,double> b;
Vector2<5,double> c = a + b;
```

won't even compile. Since this code is part of a numerical analysis package, execution speed is of the essence, and I have to assume that the authors would have considered such things.  This style is used throughout the code for vectors, matrices, and other objects that are to be interpreted as elements of numerically-parametrized sets (i.e. vector spaces of varying dimension).

So, my question is,

> > Are there any execution-speed considerations that would imply a preference for the constructor-parameter method vs. the template-parameter method?

Comment: What's the point of this class?

Comment: @Seth; the point is to have objects for use in numerical linear algebra.

Comment: I just reread the question and saw the _as if_. Before, I was wondering what the point of the `Vector2` class was, but now I see it was just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course. If the vector size is a runtime parameter, then binary operations must check at runtime that operand sizes agree.

Ideally, a C++ numerical package should provide templates with runtime-specified sizes and compile-time-specified sizes, and they should be interchangeable. Specifying size at compile time can only improve performance.

You could implement your suggestion by replacing `std::vector` in the given implementation with `std::array`/`boost::array`. If the template parameter is only used to define a runtime parameter, nothing is gained.

Answer (score 2):

> i.e. vector spaces of varying dimension

If the dimension is not known at compile time, it can't be a template parameter.  Period.

Templates are more powerful at compile time, but at the cost of some flexibility at runtime.

Comment: In this example, not using templates wouldn't be any more flexible, because you just move the size check to runtime, which is of course, however minutely, slower.